# How to find highest kernel density point

Tags: r, kernel-density, spatstat

I've been using spatstat to analyse point patterns in R. Here's an example to put this in context:

```
library(spatstat)
library(maptools) # to convert sp class to ppp
```

Some point data:

```
set.seed(1985)
x <- rnorm(20)
y <- rnorm(20)
p <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2))
plot(p)
```

The challenge is to find the kernel density *at each point*, not in a continuous field
aggregated as cells in a raster image, as calculated by `density` from **spatstat**:

`p <- as.ppp(p)
d <- density.ppp(p, sigma = 0.3)
plot(d)`

[image]

From this one can identify [clusters and other useful things](http://robinlovelace.net/r/2014/03/21/clustering-points-R.html), but it does not provide imediate insight into
the point that has the highest dot density. So this is a two-part question:

1. How to extract the coordinates of the pixel with the highest density in `d`?
2. Is there a way to calculate the kernel density only for the 20 points in `p`?

Comment: `p=as.ppp(p)` fails (R 3.1.1, latest spatstat) "Can't interpret X as a point pattern"...

Comment: Ah yes @Spacedman, forgot to add maptools dependency. Should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd convert the output to a raster object. Then:

```
require(spatstat)
require(sp)
require(raster)
set.seed(1985)
x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
p <- SpatialPoints(coords = matrix(c(x, y), ncol = 2))
plot(p)
```

Then compute densities:

```
pp = ppp(x,y) # all points in a (0,1) default window
d <- density.ppp(pp, sigma = 0.1)
dp <- density.ppp(pp, sigma = 0.1, at="points")
```

That's Q2 answered! For Q1 I turn to the raster package:

```
dr = raster(d)
xyFromCell(dr, which.max(dr))
             x          y
[1,] 0.1523438 0.00390625
```

Note this is on slightly different data than you because I did it with data on a (0,1) square. Now I've got `maptools` your max point comes out here:

```
> dr = raster(d)
> xyFromCell(dr, which.max(dr))
           x         y
[1,] 1.33514 0.3392474
```

Comment: There is an extra `=` in `pp = = ppp(x,y)`.

Comment: Fixed. Must always do a final run through. Thanks!

Comment: This is awesome! How could anyone have guessed about the `at` argument in `density.ppp`? Just shows it's important to read the documentation as it's in there. That will save lots of computational time. Your answer will save lots of brain time, thanks!

Comment: I didn't guess - I read the help for density.ppp!